# How do I indent or use tabs to separate a multi-part question while using an array environment for aligning equal signs (see picture for details)?

Tags: indentation, enumitem, arrays

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
Let \(f(x)=2x^2-12x+13\)
    \begin{enumerate}[(a)]
        \item Express $f$ in standard form.
        \begin{align*}
            f(x)&=2x(x-6x)+13 \\
            &=2x(x-6x+9)+13-(2\times9) \\
            &=2x(x-3)^2-5
        \end{align*}
    \end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image: Example of what it should look like]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this (just item a)?

**Edit:**
It seems that in your document you like to have `\parident` equal to zero and that at all list item labels start at left border of text. This can be obtain with changes in y first version of MWE, which are now marked by `% <---`:

[image]

(red lines indicate text block borders)

```
\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage{geometry}
%---------------- show page layout. don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%
\usepackage{lipsum}% For dummy text. Don't use in a real document

\usepackage{enumitem}                           % <--- 
\setlist[enumerate]{label=(\textbf{\alph*}),    % <--- 
                    align=left,                 % <--- 
                    leftmargin=*}               % <--- 
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{amsmath}
\setlength\parindent{0pt}                       % <---

\begin{document}
Let \(f(x)=2x^2-12x+13\)

    \begin{enumerate} % <---
\item   Since the coefficient of $x^2$ is not 1, \dots

    \begin{tblr}{colspec={@{} Q[l,m, mode=math]@{\,} 
                              Q[l,m, mode=math] 
                              X[l,m, font=\small\linespread{0.84}\selectfont,
                                fg=cyan7]},
                row{Z} = {belowsep+=1ex}
                }
f(x)    
    & = f(x)=2x^2-12x+13
        &                                               \\
    & = 2x(x-6x)+13             
        & Factor 2 from the $x$ terms                   \\
    & = 2x(x-6x+\textcolor{red}{9})+13-(2\cdot\textcolor{red}{9}) 
        & {Complete the square: Add 9 inside\\
           parenthesis, subtract $2\cdot 9$ outside}    \\
    & =2 x(x-3)^2-5
        & Factor 2 from the $x$ terms   
    \end{tblr}
    The standard form is ...
\item   From the standard form of $f$ we can ...
    \end{enumerate}
\item   Since the coefficient of $x^2$ is not 1, \dots

    \begin{tblr}{colspec={@{} Q[l,m, mode=math]@{\,} 
                              Q[l,m, mode=math] 
                              X[l,m, font=\small\linespread{0.84}\selectfont,
                                fg=cyan7]},
                row{Z} = {belowsep+=1ex}
                }
f(x)    
    & = f(x)=2x^2-12x+13
        &                                               \\
    & = 2x(x-6x)+13             
        & Factor 2 from the $x$ terms                   \\
    & = 2x(x-6x+\textcolor{red}{9})+13-(2\cdot\textcolor{red}{9}) 
        & {Complete the square: Add 9 inside\\
           parenthesis, subtract $2\cdot 9$ outside}    \\
    & =2 x(x-3)^2-5
        & Factor 2 from the $x$ terms   
    \end{tblr}
    The stabdard form is ...
\item   From the standard form of $f$ we can ...
    \end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Comment: How do I align the first sentence of the question - Let f(x)... - to the left side, then put the letters (a), (b), ... indented to the right below the first sentence?

Comment: @anon \noindent Let...

Comment: @anon, sorry, your MWE is not very close to showed image ... and produce indented first line in paragraphs. INow I guess, that you may like to add `\setlength\parident{0pt}` in document preamble as I add in edited answer.

Comment: How did you find the command for \setlength\parindent{0pt}? I'm looking at the documentation for enumitem package and it mentions parindent, but not how to use it or the right location (preamble) to place it?

Comment: @anon, it is TeX primitive. Descripštion you can find in The TeXbook or on internet in https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Articles/How_to_change_paragraph_spacing_in_LaTeX#Using_TeX.2FLaTeX_parameter_commands .